# zsh completion: do not offer same directory when completing for "cd"

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

When I have two directories and I `cd` to `aaa1`:

```
$~ ls
aaa1  aaa2
$~ cd aaa1
```

Now if I want to `cd` to `../aaa2` and use completion:

```
$~/aaa1 cd ../a<TAB>
aaa1  aaa2
```

zsh is offering me same directory that I am in.

Is it possible to tell zsh completion to ignore the current directory in such situation, as it most likely makes no sense to change into same directory using `cd ../aaa1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```bsh
zstyle ':completion:*' ignore-parents 'parent pwd directory'
```

See http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-ignore_002dparents_002c-completion-style

---

PS: You are so often asking Zsh completion questions, perhaps you might be interested in [the `zsh-autocomplete` plugin](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete). It ships with a very mature completion config (so you don't have to spend so much time fiddling) and adds IDE-style real-time type-ahead autocompletion to your command line.

Comment: Or type `info zsh ignore-parents`